# Ubuntu software updater failing to download repo information

Tags: 18.04, update-manager

Whenever I open Software Updater, it tries to download the repository information for updates and then it fails and shows `Failed to download repository information, check your internet connection`, even though my computer is connected to the internet. I tried changing the server location from the local server to the main server in the update managers setting. But then it shows,

```
E:The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/sublime-text-3/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file., W:Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default., W:See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details., W:An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian binary/ Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY FCEF32E745F2C3D5, W:Target Packages (Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:51 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sublime-text.list:1, W:Target Translations (en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:51 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sublime-text.list:1, E:Failed to fetch http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/ubuntu-upstart/dists/dist/InRelease  Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NOSPLIT' (does the network require authentication?), E:The repository 'http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/ubuntu-upstart dist InRelease' is not signed.
```

Can someone tell me what is the issue here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What can I do if a repository/PPA does not have a Release file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/866901/what-can-i-do-if-a-repository-ppa-does-not-have-a-release-file). Your problem is a dead PPA, which is unrelated to the repository server -- you changed the wrong setting.

Comment: PPAs are 3rd party repositories, so all security checks (is it well supported, maintained, trustworthy etc) are on you.